# An algorithm to find the bucket to which the item ID will be assigned

Tags: python

A company wishes to bucketize their item IDs for better search operations. The bucket for the item ID is chosen on the basis of the maximum value of the digit in the item ID. Write and algorithm to find the bucket to which the item ID will be assigned.

Input : the input consists of an integer itemID, representing the identity number of the item.

Output: Print an integer representing the bucket to which the item ID will be assigned

I have used python language for solving the same and have taken input as an array of numbers. for example: input >4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 2

```
itemID = input(">")
bucket = itemID[0]
for item in itemID:
    if item > bucket:
        bucket = item
print(bucket)
```

Comment: Please guide me if the solution to this question is accurate

Comment: Do you think there are any problems with what you have written? You need to actually ask a question in order to get it answered.

Comment: wanted a check to my solution, because the question actually tricks me in some sense

Comment: It sounds like you should generate some test cases where you propose a number of inputs and then predict the consequent output in each case, and then run your program to see which of the inputs produces the right output and which does not.

Answer (score -1):

```
itemID = input(">")
bucket = itemID[0]
for item in itemID:
    if item > bucket:
        bucket = item
print(bucket)
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.